# Overwrite specific Hive partition directory in Amazon S3

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I want to overwrite specific Hive partitions directory in S3.

**Nature of Data:**

1. 27GB of parquet data.
2. 2 partition cols("**geo**" and "**dateCol**") for instance s3 location looks like this `s3://bucket-name/DeliveryTable/ltst/geo=AP/dateCol=2020-10-04`
3. 6K~ partition in AmazonS3.

**Cycle of Hive table Update.**

1. Daily updates on specific partitions.
2. total number of partitions altered/Overwritten are ~100 out of 6k.

**Things tried**

1. `pyspark_df.repartition("geo","dateCol").write.insertInto("hive_ext_table", overwrite=True)`
2. `pyspark_df.write.save("s3://bucket-name/DeliveryTable/ltst")`

**Some Observations**

- using `insertInto` overwrites specific partition as I wanted but takes alot of time for the job to complete as Spark creates staging directory on S3 and it does a lazy copy to the partition cols. This process takes 3 - 8 hours to complete.
- going with `save()` is overwriting all the data that is currently there in S3 location, although the job finishes faster than `insertInto`, it deletes all the data that is all 6k partition directory.

I want to use `Save` but how can I overwrite just the specific partitions as data received is dynamic and If I have to use `save('partition-dir')`, I will have to end up creating 100 save statements as there are approximately 100 partitions for updates.

Is this a recommended approach or is there a better solution to this. ?

Comment: S3 is notoriously slow (still), need to check settings...

Comment: Your first solution appears fine to me, S3 notorious slow. Check postings on the way S3 does commits, eventual consistency. See https://medium.com/@routdeepak/writing-to-aws-s3-from-spark-91e85d09724b. 2nd solution is of course a no-goer.

Comment: @thebluephantom with first approach what I ended up is doing a complete scan on the 27GB sized table along with union on the updated partition which are like 80-100 partitions having close to 100 MB data. This is the behaviour I noticed in Spark UI by analyzing the query when I use insertInto .

Comment: What I think you r saying is that with S3 things are slow, as opposed to non-S3-based-HDFS.

Comment: http://cloudsqale.com/2019/12/30/spark-slow-load-into-partitioned-hive-table-on-s3-direct-writes-output-committer-algorithms/ how about this?